# Adding controls dynamically in form issue

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

I am working on a little project and when i'm trying to generate a list from a array, the created control is overwritten after adding it so I can only see the last generated one. Is there something that i'm doing not correctly ? Here the code :

```
    string[] radios = { "fillydelphia_radio", "brony_radio", "luna_radio", "alicorn_radio",
                              "sonic_radioboom", "fractured_frequencies", "ponyville_fm",
                              "everypony_radio", "wonderbolt_radio", "best_pony_radio",
                              "pegabit_sounds" };

    public List()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        generateInfo();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string l in radios)
        {
            Label tempname = radioName as Label;
            PictureBox templogo = radioLogo as PictureBox;
            templogo.Name = l + "logo";
            templogo.Location = new Point(templogo.Location.X, templogo.Location.Y + i);
            templogo.ImageLocation = RadiosInfo.getRadioInfo(l, "logo");
            tempname.Name = l + "name";
            tempname.Location = new Point(tempname.Location.X, tempname.Location.Y + i);
            tempname.Text = RadiosInfo.getRadioInfo(l, "name");
            SuspendLayout();
            this.Controls.Add(tempname);
            this.Controls.Add(templogo);
            ResumeLayout();
            i += 50;
        }
    }

    private PictureBox radioLogo = new PictureBox();
    private Label radioName = new Label();
    private Label radioArtist = new Label();
    private Label radioSong = new Label();
    private Label radioGenre = new Label();
```

Sorry for the long code and for my spelling mistake, first time posting here and i'm not english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing the controls (radioName and radioLogo) in each iteration. So instead of adding a whole bunch of controls, you are simply changing the properties of the existing controls.

What you'll want to do is create new controls each time. For example:

```
foreach (string l in radios)
{
    Label tempname = new Label();
    PictureBox templogo = new PictureBox();
    ....
```

On another note, it'll be more efficient to call SuspendLayout() before your foreach loop, and ResumeLayout() after your foreach loop.